# Android continue after checking and requesting permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I know there are many questions answered regarding checking and requesting permission and handling their response and I am clear on that. But what I bit confuse about is if we are checking for same permission for two different things, how do we continue task after permission is granted?

For example,I have recycleView and in my adapter I have code for two buttons, one would save file and another one would save and open activity to share that file with other app.

```
MyRecycleAdapter {

Context context:

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
           if(checkPermission()) {
               have permission
               save file to disk
          } else {
              requestPermission
               save file to disk
           }  
     }
});
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
           if(checkPermission()) {
               have permission
               save file to disk
               open share activity using (context)
          } else {
              requestPermission
               save file to disk
              open share activity using (context)
           }  
     }
});

}
```

Comment: first, implement `View.OnClickListener` in our adapter then its override method `onClick` then create boolean variable of class level then check this boolean condition of permission check if boolean if false that means you can to check permission if not your can continue normally

Comment: yes but question is on getting permision response how do I know if I need to save and share the file or just save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use different request codes to control what happens after permission is granted:

```
final int SAVE = 1;
final int SAVE_AND_SHARE = 2;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
  Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this,
    new String[]{
      android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    },
    [either SAVE or SAVE_AND_SHARE]);
} else {
  //permission is already granted, continue
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] 
  grantResults) {
  if (requestCode == SAVE) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0
      && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
      //save
    } else {
      //permission was denied
    }
  } else if (requestCode == SAVE_AND_SHARE) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0
      && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
      //save and share
    } else {
      //permission was denied
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this solves problem but would prefer if there was a way to pause current flow while getting permission and then continue if permission granted. Not sure if this is possible but this would be much clear way to do.

Comment: This does that. When the permission is requested the user gets a popup, asking them if they approve or deny the permission request.

Comment: yes this solution works not a problem with that. I am just think if I have 10 different task requiring same permission i would have about 9 if conditions (or case: ) to so what thought would be much clean code woud be some thing like

task1 {
if(!permission) {
   if(!await requestPermission())
              return;
}
performTask
}

Comment: this is just my thought, as I said may not be possible.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, I would make another field for the action to be performed, which is updated in the onClick listeners. Then in onRequestPermissionsResult after verifying PERMISSION_GRANTED, you can add a switch statement or if-block which determines which action is taken based on that field.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completion. Requesting permissions has been simplified lately in the API. Here's how I check for a permission before doing some action:

```
private lateinit var requestPermissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Permission callback
    val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Yay, permission was granted
            doSomething()
        }
        else {
            // Boo, permission was refused
            Snackbar.make(root,"Wut ?! We need your permission!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun checkLocationPermissionAndDoSomething() {

    // Do we have the permission ?
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Permission is not granted. Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Explanation is needed. Show dialog
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            builder.setTitle("Please")
            builder.setMessage("We need to use your location because bla blah bla.")
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ ->
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            }
            builder.show()
        }
        else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        }
    } else {

        // Permission has already been granted
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

When multiple permissions are needed just use ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions and use an array of permissions